# Save value to firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have in a method in which a calculation is carried out to obtain the price of a trip

I want to recover the value of "calculate_item_price" to save it in the Firebase database

How do I do this?

thank you

```
private void estimatePriceRead(){


                String requestUrl=null;
                try {
                    requestUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"+
                            "mode=driving&"
                            +"transit_routing_preference=less_driving&"
                            +"origin="+(mCurrentRide.getPickup().getName())+"&"
                            +"destination="+(mCurrentRide.getDestination().getName())+"&"
                            +"key="+getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
                    Log.e("LINK",requestUrl);
                    mService.getPath(requestUrl).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                                JSONArray routes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                                JSONObject object = routes.getJSONObject(0);
                                JSONArray legs = object.getJSONArray("legs");

                                JSONObject legsObject = legs.getJSONObject(0);

                                //Get distance
                                JSONObject distance = legsObject.getJSONObject("distance");
                                String distance_text = distance.getString("text");
                                //use regex to extract double from string
                                //This regex will remove all text not digit
                                Double distance_value= Double.parseDouble(distance_text.replaceAll("[^0-9\\\\.]+",""));

                                //Get Time
                                JSONObject time = legsObject.getJSONObject("duration");
                                String time_text = time.getString("text");
                                Integer time_value = Integer.parseInt(time_text.replaceAll("\\D+",""));

                                calculate_item_price = String.format("%.2f €",
                                        TypeObject.getPrice(distance_value,time_value));
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: all works fine i just want to know how to save the value of "calculate_item_price" in the firebase database
and i don't know how to do that

Comment: What have you tried for that?

Comment: nothing i'm new in android programming

Answer (score 0):

Try by making a model class with all the variables you wish to add to Firebase Database and then push under "ride_info" reference. Something like this

```
 public class Ride{
    String customerId;
    String calculate_item_price;
    
    public Ride(){
    //empty constructor for firebase
    }
}
```

then push add data and push it to firebase

```
 public void postRideInfo(){
    rideRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ride_info");

    id =  rideRef.push().getKey();
    String customerId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    Ride ride = new Ride(customerId,calculate_item_price);
    rideRef.child(id).setValue(ride);
}
```